# Multiple Models in 1 view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm still wrapping my head around MVC and I've moved from the single Model application to one that is more complicated (multi-model).

I have set up my models in a Code First way so that EF can create my database and tables for me.

Let's say I have a Person model that has:

- Name
- Phone
- Address
- City
- StateId

Then I have a State model that has:

- StateId
- State

I have created my Controllers & Views for both of these models.

In my Person Edit View I would like to display a combo-box of all the states that are currently in my State table.

In my view I only see the:

```
@model IEnumerable<myProject.Models.Person>
```

I don't see a way to include all of the state names so I can populate a combo box.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Quickest way to it put it in the ViewBag and access it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a view model is the right way to go.  You can then create a private method on your controller to build the `SelectList` each time.  This approach prevents you from having to sacrifice compile-time safety, which you would do if you used `ViewBag`.

So first up, the view model could look something like this:

```
public class EditPersonViewModel
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "State")]
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public SelectList States { get; set; }
}
```

The reason I have the `StateId` property in there, even though we could access that via the `Person` object, is because in this case, `Person` is the model and, in my mind, I think it doesn't make sense to be placing data annotations on the model.  That aside, the `Display` annotation simply allows you to control what text is rendered when using `LabelFor` to provide a text label for your `States` `SelectList`.

Before I get into building the list, let's define a simple class to hold a state:

```
public class State
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Next up, we need to be able to build the `SelectList`.  To do that, you can add a private method to your controller:

```
private SelectList GetStates(object selectedValue = null)
{
    return new SelectList(this.States, StateListDataValueKey,
                   StateListDataTextKey, selectedValue);
}
```

`this.States` represents wherever you fetch/store your state data.  So it could be something like `db.States.GetAll()`.

`StateListDataValueKey` and `StateListDataTextKey` represent the names of the fields you want to use as the selected value and selected text, respectively.  So in this case, `StateListDataValueKey` should be `Id` and `StateListDataTextKey` should be `Name`.  I tend to define these in my controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // rest of controller

    // These two strings should correspond with
    // the properties in your State class
    private readonly string StateListDataValueKey = "Id";
    private readonly string StateListDataTextKey = "Name";
}
```

We can now move on to creating the actions to display the data for a person, and also for the editing of a person:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var model = new EditPersonViewModel();
    // Get a person by Id.
    model.Person = GetPerson(id);
    // Call the utility method to build the list.
    model.States = GetStates(model.Person.StateId);

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(EditPersonViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Save the edits and then redirect.
        return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index");
    }

    // Build the SelectList again so we can repopulate the view.
    model.States = GetStates(model.Person.StateId);

    return View(model);
}
```

Now that's out the way, let's take a look at the relevant part of the edit view:

```
@model EditPersonViewModel

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StateId)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Person.StateId, Model.States)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.States)
</div>
```

The call to `LabelFor` uses the `Display` data annotation defined earlier to correctly label the drop down list.  Otherwise it would be labelled with the text 'StateId', which isn't useful to your users.

## Update

The two private fields that I specified in the controller were bugging me a bit, as it's not the best way of doing things.  I've left that approach there in case you prefer it but here's a better implementation:

```
private SelectList BuildSelectList<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Expression<Func<TSource, int>> valueKey, Expression<Func<TSource, string>> textKey,
    object selectedValue = null)
{
    var selectedValueKey = ((MemberExpression)(MemberExpression)valueKey.Body).Member.Name;
    var selectedTextKey = ((MemberExpression)(MemberExpression)textKey.Body).Member.Name;

    return new SelectList(source, selectedValueKey, selectedTextKey, selectedValue);
}
```

Notice how I've made the method generic and I've changed the name.  Now, you can use it to build any `SelectList`, instead of just one for states.  You can use it like so:

```
model.States = BuildSelectList(this.States, m => m.Id, m => m.Name, model.Person.StateId);
```

You no longer need to define `StateListDataValueKey` or `StateListDataTextKey` in your controller.

Comment: Wow!  Thank you for this excellent post.  I appreciate the time you put into it to help me understand it.  I do have a question or two.  The first one is the controller code.  Was that to the person controller?  If so, I'm having an issue in the Create Action  trying to pass in a model into db.Person.Add(model) doesn't work.  I need an Person entity.  Do you know how I can use your code for the Create Action?

Comment: could it something like this?  db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Added;  db.SaveChanges();

Comment: @webdad3 You're welcome!  For some reason I messed up an edit.  It was actually just the default `HomeController` that I tested with.  As for the creation action, you need to remember that the model type that's passed to the action would be a view model such as `CreatePersonViewModel`.  That means you need to make sure you're passing `model.Person` to Entity Framework and not simply `model`.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least 2 ways of doing this.  The easiest, "quick and dirty" way is to use ViewBag/ViewData/Session and store the list of states there.  One (better IMO) alternative is to create a ViewModel that will contain a Person, a collection of States, and perhaps which State was selected.  It would look something like this:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    public State SelectedState { get; set; }

    // this might also be IEnumerable<SelectListItem> depending on what you want to do.
    public IEnumerable<State> States { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in the constructor, call methods that fill the ViewModel with data.  Bind that ViewModel to your View, and use it however you see fit.